# How to display/preview directly an image file attached in a custom object with the help of lwc, without using preview button

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-dom

**.js file**

```js
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';

// importing Apex class method
import retriveFiles from '@salesforce/apex/LWCExampleController.retriveFiles';

// importing navigation service
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

// extends the class to 'NavigationMixin'
export default class FilePrivewInLWC extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    // reactive variables
    @track files;

    // Reteriving the files to preview
    @wire(retriveFiles)
    filesData({data, error}) {
        if(data) {
            window.console.log('data ===> '+data);
            this.files = data;
        }
        else if(error) {
            window.console.log('error ===> '+JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    }

    // when you click the preview button this method will call and
    // it will show the preview of the file based on ContentDocumentId
    filePreview(event) {
        // Naviagation Service to the show preview
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__namedPage',
            attributes: {
                pageName: 'filePreview'
            },
            state : {
                // assigning ContentDocumentId to show the preview of file
                selectedRecordId:event.currentTarget.dataset.id
            }
          })
    }
}
```

**.html file**

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card title="File Preview In Lightning Web Component">
        <template if:true={files}>
            <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_cell-buffer">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="slds-text-title_caps">
                        <th scope="col">
                            <div title="Key">File Name</div>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col">
                            <div title="Value">File Extension</div>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <template for:each={files} for:item="keyValue">
                        <tr key={keyValue.Id}>
                            <th scope="col">
                                <div>{keyValue.Title}</div>
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col">
                                <div>{keyValue.FileExtension}</div>
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col">    
                                <!-- Using Dataset Property to get ContentDocumentId -->
                                <lightning-button data-id={keyValue.ContentDocumentId} 
                                                  label="Preview" 
                                                  variant="brand" 
                                                  value="file preview" 
                                                  onclick={filePreview}></lightning-button>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </template>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an `img` tag and pass the ContentDocument to that.

It looks like you are querying to the ContentVersion records so it's good.
Form the URL like below and put that into a list.

```
item.url = '/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/' + contentVersion.Id;
```

So the wire method will be like this.

```
@wire(retriveFiles)
filesData({data, error}) {
    if(data) {
        window.console.log('data ===> '+data);
        this.files = data.map( image => {
             ...image,
             url: '/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/' + image .Id
        });
    }
    else if(error) {
        window.console.log('error ===> '+JSON.stringify(error));
    }
}
```

Do this in the HTML.

```
<template for:each={files} for:item="keyValue">
    <tr key={keyValue.Id}>
        <th scope="col">
            <div>{keyValue.Title}</div>
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
            <div>{keyValue.FileExtension}</div>
        </th>
        <th scope="col">    
            <img src={keyValue.url}/>
        </th>
    </tr>
</template>
```